# tensorflow.keras.models running into error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

installed keras
installed keras.utils
installed tensorflow==2 (due to class requirement)

i have installed, uninstalled and re-installed
all using pip

VM machine, windows 10 pro version 1903, 64bit, intel xeon X5670

have not been able to debug and now working on trying another computer to see if I can see a change.

error below

```
ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-10-ea80743cf695>", line 1, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . _api.v2 import audio
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\_api\v2\audio\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_audio_ops import decode_wav
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_audio_ops.py", line 9, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2040, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'ImportError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1101, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 319, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 353, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 1502, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 1460, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 733, in getmodule
    if ismodule(module) and hasattr(module, '__file__'):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . _api.v2 import audio
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\_api\v2\audio\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_audio_ops import decode_wav
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_audio_ops.py", line 9, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-10-ea80743cf695>", line 1, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . _api.v2 import audio
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\_api\v2\audio\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_audio_ops import decode_wav
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_audio_ops.py", line 9, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2040, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'ImportError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.


ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-10-ea80743cf695>", line 1, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . _api.v2 import audio
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\_api\v2\audio\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_audio_ops import decode_wav
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_audio_ops.py", line 9, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2040, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'ImportError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3249, in run_ast_nodes
    if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3343, in run_code
    self.showtraceback(running_compiled_code=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2043, in showtraceback
    value, tb, tb_offset=tb_offset)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1385, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1288, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1150, in structured_traceback
    formatted_exceptions += self.prepare_chained_exception_message(evalue.__cause__)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2040, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'TypeError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1101, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 319, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 353, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 1502, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 1460, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 733, in getmodule
    if ismodule(module) and hasattr(module, '__file__'):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . _api.v2 import audio
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\_api\v2\audio\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_audio_ops import decode_wav
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_audio_ops.py", line 9, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

Comment: there is more to the error, but limited in char. - p[ython version 3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling, it turns out that I should have not used `pip install`. I uninstalled all pip libraries related to [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org). Switched to anaconda installation.

```
conda install tensorflow==2
```

[Jupyter notebook](https://jupyter.org/) is able now to run through libraries with no issue.

I also added some additional paths to scripts in the debugging process.